# Add multiple UITableViews inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I want to add a tabs pager view with 5 tabs and each tab contain uitableview as subview on uitableviewcell . The problem at the height of each uitableview , I should update the cell height every the user swipe or press on any tab and reload the tableview each time . Is it correct ? . Sometimes, the view is hanged . So Is there any solution for this problem .

[image]

Thank you,

Nada Gamal

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Can you provide a visual?

Comment: @nada Canal Each tab contain uitableview as subview on uitableviewcell.Means you have 5 tab bars on which you have table view and each table view cell has one more table view that's what are you trying to say?

Comment: @Frankie I updated the question with visual screenshot . Thank you for your support :)

Comment: @TusharSharma  I updated the question with visual screenshot . Thank you for your support :)

Comment: @NadaGamal Why does each tab contain a table view instead of just using buttons or making the 6 tabs part of a collection view within the tableviewcell?  What does tapping a tab do?  Does it reload the cell below it?  Why is your entire interface contained in one big tableview?  Just trying to understand because at the moment it seems like this should be architected differently.

Comment: @Frankie Because each tab is contain a list of data and it should be a tableview . The big UITableView is contains 2 cells the above match info cell and the other is the tabs view , And when I tap or swipe at any tab , I reload the UTableviewcell to update the cell height at big uitableview . May be I select an incorrect way . So Please advice me :) . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the architecture of the app is a bit off. You sure should avoid such a deep nesting of tableViews within tableViews. There are multiple & excellent native UI alternatives like a [StackViews](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview) or traditional UIScrollViews, Collection Views that you should consider utilizing.
Such a hierarchy of tableViews is *definitely* not recommended & you should evaluate alternate implementation strategies rather than waste valuable time debugging this.